# Twitter like follow system with CodeIgniter and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, codeigniter, twitter-follow

I'm currently programming a subscribers / followers system like on twitter and facebook with CodeIgniter.

So, the idea is to create a link on he users' profil page and give the opportunity to the users to follow artist or promotor on the website and see the news and feeds of them.

Basically this is the same idea has twitter.

How can we create a think like that with just a link.

For the moment, I have a database with the id of the follower, the id of the artist.
If one user want to follow an other, he click on the link and one row is add in the database with this two values, if he click one more time, the row is deleted from the database and the users in 'unfollow'

I create an anchor link like this:

`anchor('follow','Follow',array('id'=>'follow','data-id' => '2'));`

wich mean on my screen, I have

a href="http://localhost:8888/sanyproject/follow" id="follow" data-id="2"

For the ajax part I have create this:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$('#follow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "profile/follow",
      data: { id : $('#follow').attr('data-id')}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data: " + msg );
    }).error(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

});

So, now the idea is to send to my controller profile/follow the id of the artist and insert or delete the value in my database.

I really, really don't know how to do it, this is my first app on CodeIgniter, so I take all constructed advice!

Comment: $('#follow').data('id') is the same as $('#follow').attr('data-id') :)

Comment: so what is wrong with your code? any errors? what is your follow method doing? is it receiving the id?

Comment: @Gerep : Nothing is happening, I have directly the second alert (error) so I don't know what's wrong with my code and I can't find where is my error :(

Comment: install firebug, it will show you the errors...using it on chrome the shortcut is `CTRL+SHIFT+J`, run the code, click the button and then the shortcut, it will show you the error(s) if there is any

Comment: @Gerep :  Thanks you Gerep ! I'm such an idiot ! I had a 404 error! Now, I fixed the problem and Everything is fine !! Thanks you ! Have a Nice day/night

Comment: Glad to help, please answer your question with your solution, it will help others.

Comment: @Gerep : gonna post it tomorrow, can't now cause I don't have 100 reputation :) Thanks again !!

Comment: @Simon: Please, when you have find an answer that solves your problem, please **accept** it by clicking at its **green tick**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to u guys, I found the error on my script and now it works perfectly!

This is the answer to the code

In the javascript function change this line:

url: $('#follow').attr('href')

and add

`type: 'POST'`

so now you have :

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$('#follow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#follow').attr('href'),
    data: { id : $('#follow').data('id')}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data: " + msg );
    }).error(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

});

and for the PHP change de line with :

echo anchor('profile/follow','Follow',array('id'=>'follow','data-id' => '2'));

So the first parameters is the link to the function to do the follow/unfollow (do as you want with your function), now you have to create your controller and your model to insert or delete in your database.

OFC, data-id is gonna be dynamic and the artist-id id gonna be at the place of '2'

Hope it's clear for everyone :)

Apologize for my bad english and again, thanks.

Have a nice day !

Simon